# PHP Error Connecting to Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Background Information:
I am trying to create a TODO App

```
<?php 
require_once 'app/init.php';

$itemsQuery = $db->prepare("
SELECT id, name, done
FROM items
WHERE user = :user
");
$itemsQuery->execute([
'user' => $_SESSION['user_id']
]);

$items = $itemsQuery->rowCount() ? $itemsQuery : [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
echo $item['name'], '<br>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Darshil Patel</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="list">
        <h1 class="header">To do.</h1>

    <ul class="items">
        <li>
            <span class="item">Pick Up Shopping</span>
            <a href="#" class="done-button">Mark as done</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="item-add" action="add.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Add a New Item"         class="input" autocomplete="off" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

INIT.PHP:

```
<? php

session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] =  1;

$db = new PDO('msql_dbname= u352634928_list;host=mysql.hostinger.co.uk', 'mysql.hostinger.co.uk', 'password');

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
die('You are not signed in');
}
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid
> data source name' in /home/u352634928/public_html/app/init.php:7 Stack
> trace: #0 /home/u352634928/public_html/app/init.php(7):
> PDO->__construct('msql_dbname=u35...', 'u352634928_list', 'password')
>
> ## 1 /home/u352634928/public_html/index.php(2): require_once('/home/u35263492...') #2 {main} thrown in
>
> /home/u352634928/public_html/app/init.php on line 7

Comment: Even after fixing it I am getting another error

Comment: check my ans @Darshil Patel

Comment: @ParthChavda I did what you told me and now I am getting this new error,

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''u352634928_list'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/u352634928/public_html/app/init.php on line 7

The Domain I have uploaded the project too is: darshil.xyz

Comment: Update the question to your code.

Comment: You should reset your DB password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have left a space between the `<?` and the `php`. So at the very first do it `<?php`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'session_start' (T_STRING) in /home/u352634928/public_html/app/init.php on line 3

Comment: You did the same in the session file

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo:

Change

```
<? php
```

To

```
<?php
```

Basically, all PHP statements end with semi colon `;`.

And in your case, your PHP starts with `<?` you have added space before `php`.

So, `php` is a statement and that is not ended with `;`.

That is the reason behind parse error.

Comment: Again, do the same thing in init.php, it will work now.

Comment: I am getting a new error 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name' in /home/u352634928/public_html/app/init.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/u352634928/public_html/app/init.php(7): PDO->__construct('msql_dbname=u35...', 'u352634928_list', 'Saibaba2') #1 /home/u352634928/public_html/index.php(2): require_once('/home/u35263492...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/u352634928/public_html/app/init.php on line 7

Darshil.xyz, that's my domain

Answer (score 1):

change `<? php` to `<?php`, remove the space in between.

[require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

[pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: Even after fixing it I am getting another error 
darshil.xyz(see for yourself)

Comment: I have fixed my question to the new error I am getting

Comment: i think you have lot of syntax error's,each time you are posting different error lines 1,2,3.,update your errors properly only then others can help you out

Comment: @sa-7
What does this error mean?

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''u352634928_list'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/u352634928/public_html/app/init.php on line 7

Answer (score 1):

This is the right syntax to connect with Mysql database :

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);
```

for you

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql.hostinger.co.uk;dbname= u352634928_list", 'mysql.hostinger.co.uk', 'password');
```

Comment: Thanks, that part work but now I am getting a new error 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''u352634928_list'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/u352634928/public_html/app/init.php on line 7

Comment: and please when you change the code add that code also in your question